# Exceptions in N2cms page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, n2cms

i'm using n2cms + asp.net mvc,
when the site is uploaded to a webserver, and an exception is thrown in the aspx page, the page appear blank, and there is nothing in the page, even if i turned off the CustomErrors in web.config

but when the site is running on my computer visual studio simply show me the exception,

is there a way to catch the exception in this situation?

Answer (score 2):

This may be due to your hosting configuration.  You could take a look at [ELMAH](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/) for an easy way of logging exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

You can handle all global errors in your Global.asax's method called Application_Error - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/24395wz3.aspx . It will work for simple cases. But I strongly recommend to use [ELMAH](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/)

Comment: i already used that event, and I'm using log4net to log the exception, but  the exception is handled before reaches to the Application_Error event

Answer (score 0):

`N2CMS` makes calls to `SwallowExceptions()`.  This is why you are receiving a blank page instead of an exception.  You could look for that method call and comment it.